# How to access event of an ActiveX control in ASP.net that is in object tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, activexobject

I have this object tag in asp.net and successfully integrated it and show it on my website

```
<object id="enrollmentform" classid="clsid:0B4409EF-FD2B-4680-9519-D18C52XXXXX"></object>
```

My question is how can i use the event that its in the activexcontrol. kindy see image below.

[image]

Comment: What exactly to you want to do? Why are you using an ActiveX control which will only work in IE, and not even Edge?

Comment: Would like to integrate fingerprint module in it, and want to know if we can access the event that its in the screenshot. Company want to integrate this in asp.net